# How to get result from SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog back to C#?

Tags: web-part, javascript, modal-dialog, popup

I have a code on a visual web part user control (see below):
Could you please advice, how to get value from the callback function back to the C# in code behind to process it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function portal_BaseCallback(result, value) {
        if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
        // here I need to transfer value to C# code behind to process
        }
        if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
        //user press Cancel, ignore it
        }
    }
    function GetBaseOptions(m_title, m_url, width, height) {
        var options = {
            url: m_url,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            title: m_title,
            dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null,     portal_BaseCallback)
        };
        return options;
    }
    function openDialog(options) {
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
</script>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="MyUpdatePanel">
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Id="Link01" Text="Write a letter" 
    OnClientClick="openDialog(GetBaseOptions('Write a    message','/_layouts/htmledit.aspx',1024,800));" 
    onclick="Link01_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to do what I need using hidden field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function portal_BaseCallback(result, value) {
        var hidden;
        if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
            // here I need to transfer value to C# code behind to process
            hidden = document.getElementById('<%= this.Hidden1.ClientID %>');
            if (hidden != null) {
                hidden.value = value;
                __doPostBack('<%= this.MyUpdatePanel.ClientID %>', "cmdSend");
            }
        }
        if (result === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) {
            hidden = document.getElementById('<%= this.Hidden1.ClientID %>');
            if (hidden != null) {
                hidden.value = '';
            }
            var notifyId = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Message cancelled", false);
        }
    }
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="MyUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Hidden1" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="Hidden1" onvaluechanged="Unnamed1_ValueChanged"/>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="Hidden2" />
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Id="Link01" 
        Text="Test me i'm a link" 
        OnClientClick="openDialog(GetBaseOptions('Write a message','/_layouts/htmledit.aspx',1024,800));" 
  />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Unnamed1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ //use Hidden1.Value }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to load required JS.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { alert("Hii") });
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () { alert("Hello") },"sp.js");
```

Answer (score -1):

To pass a value back to the parent page use `SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose`.

It will close the dialog with the result like “OK”, “Cancel” and can pass aditional information.

Ex:

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK, "success");

function OnPopClosed(dialogResult, retValue) {

    if (dialogResult == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
        if (retValue)
            alert(retValue);
        }
}
```

http://sptalks.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/sharepoint-modal-dialog-passing-values-back-and-forth/

http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/using-the-sharepoint-2010-modal-dialog

[SharePoint Modal Help - pass value back to parent when closing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38405/sharepoint-modal-help-pass-value-back-to-parent-when-closing)

Comment: Which has nothing to do with c#, the real problem here

Comment: If you want in C#, then one hack is there. When the Dialog window get closed. Redirect it to the parent with your info imbedded as QueryString.
Back to the parent page just check for the presence of QueryString.

Comment: The problem is I need to get this value in code behind, not in the javascript.

Comment: Yes..if you pass the values in QueryString, you can read it anywhere..js file or cs file.

Answer (score -1):

It should be as easy as to modify your function from

```
function openDialog(options) 
{
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

to

```
function openDialog(options) 
{
    var value = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Which has nothing to do with c#, the real problem here

Comment: As I understend, var value will be in this case a object of type SP.UI.ModalDialog, and it doesn't help to get returned value from callback function to the c#.