# File Drag and Drop Prompt Metadata Properties Dialog

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, drag-and-drop

When a user drags and drops a file or files into a SharePoint library, how can you enforce the metadata properties dialog box to prompt?

I found a solution through the Enhance Document Upload by Snapple, but I need something that works with Office 365.

This is what I'm looking for, but that works with SharePoint Online 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8P2BXSBwP00

Answer (score 7):

[I wrote an answer for this some time ago..](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/144824/10271)

Features are:

- Open EditForm after Drag&Drop
- Open EditForm for **multiple** files

---

Just add a ScriptEditor WebPart to your list page and apply this code:

```
(function (_window) {
    var maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc = 10000;
    function replaceUploadProgressFunc() {
        if (typeof _window.UploadProgressFunc != 'undefined') {
            _window.Base_UploadProgressFunc = _window.UploadProgressFunc;
            _window.UploadProgressFunc = Custom_UploadProgressFunc;
            console.log('replaced dialog');
        } else if (maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc > 0) {
            maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc -= 100;
            setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);


    function Custom_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state) {
        _window.Base_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state);
        var messageType = ProgressMessage.EMPTY;
        switch (state.status) {
            case 1:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.VALIDATION;
                break;
            case 3:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADING;
                break;
            case 4:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADED;
                OpenEditFormForLastItem(state);
                break;
            case 5:
                messageType = ProgressMessage.CANCELLED;
                break;
        }

        function OpenEditFormForLastItem(state) {
            var caml = '';
            caml += "<View>";
            caml += "<Query>";
            caml += "<Where>";

            if (state.files.length > 1) {
                caml += "<In>";
                caml += "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>";
                caml += "<Values>";
            } else {
                caml += "<Eq>";
                caml += "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>";
            }

            state.files.forEach(function (file) {
                //only succesfull uploaded files that arent overwrites
                console.log(file);
                if (file.status === 5 /*&& !file.overwrite*/) {
                    caml += "<Value Type='File'>" + file.fileName + "</Value>";
                }
            }, this);

            if (state.files.length > 1) {
                caml += "</Values>";
                caml += "</In>";
            } else {
                caml += "</Eq>";
            }

            caml += "</Where>";
            caml += "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";
            caml += "</Query>";
            caml += "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>";
            caml += "<RowLimit>500</RowLimit>";
            caml += "</View>";
            console.log(caml);

            var cntxt = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var web = cntxt.get_web();
            var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(window.ctx.ListTitle);
            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
            query.set_viewXml(caml);
            var items = list.getItems(query);
            cntxt.load(list, 'DefaultEditFormUrl');
            cntxt.load(items);
            cntxt.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
                function openEditForItem() {
                    if (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                        var item = listEnumerator.get_current();
                        var id = item.get_id();

                        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
                        options.title = "Add File Metadata";
                        options.url = list.get_defaultEditFormUrl() + '?ID=' + id;
                        options.autoSize = true;
                        options.dialogReturnValueCallback = openEditForItem;
                        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
                    } else {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                }
                openEditForItem();
            }, function (error, args) {
                    console.log("failed to get new uploaded items");
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(args);
                });
        }
    }
})(window);
```

Comment: This works really well, but would it be possible to edit the file to also check in the file upon save?

Comment: You could try to work with an DialogCallback. 
Examples here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/38405/10271

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it, though I think it might be a bit too complicated for me to figure out :-)

Comment: Actually I already use the callback - `openEditForItem`. You could google for the JSOM code to check in a item. Or you could try to edit this line `options.url = list.get_defaultEditFormUrl() + '?Mode=Upload&CheckInComment=&ID=' + id;` maybe that will work also.

Comment: Dude you should be further up, amazing script.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment but I couldn't edit the one above. If you would like to extend this to the whole site collection, what would be the best way to deploy? As modifying the masterpage is not the recommended way.

Comment: @Yugo you should ask a new question for that, but you could do it with a sitecollection scoped user custom action.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I have the problem, that it's not working within sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your master page and override following JavaScript function

```
function UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state) {
    state.percentDone = percentDone;
    var messageType = ProgressMessage.EMPTY;

    switch (state.status) {
        case 1:
            messageType = ProgressMessage.VALIDATION;
            break;
        case 3:
            messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADING;
            break;
        case 4:
            messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADED;
            MyNewFunction();
            break;
        case 5:
            messageType = ProgressMessage.CANCELLED;
            break;
    }
    UpdateProgressBar(messageType, state);
}
```

Source [Enforce Drag and Drop documents to apply metadata](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81330/enforce-drag-and-drop-documents-to-apply-metadata)

Comment: I read the source you attached, but wasn't 100% sure on how to apply the javascript. This is what I did and it did not work :( 1. created a new javascript file in the Style Library and copied the above script to it. 2. I created another file that housed the "window.onload function" and reference the DragDrop.Extended.js in the getScript section. 3. I copy and pasted the 3rd piece which contained the var options in a cewp on the library.

Comment: @sharepointaaron since you are using SharePoint Online. The best option is to add this script in the `head` section of the master page. I haven't tried this, but based on the link I posted it seems achievable.

Comment: I got that part, just not sure why the script isnt running for me.

Comment: You can debug it using Internet Explorer Developer Tools. You can put break point and step through to find if the function name is same for online version.