# File Drag and Drop Prompt Metadata Properties Dialog in Sub Folder in SharePoint 2016

Tags: javascript, 2016, file-upload

I used this solution to add a Meta-Data Dialog for a DocLib in SharePoint 2016
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/158373/48328

Works fine so far, but only in the root folder and not in sub folders within the library.

It seems that the state that is called in the switch command is a different one.

thx, Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some modification to the script posted in the question. Please try below revised script, I have added some additional code to set folder url while retrieving the document uploaded.

```
(function (_window) {
    var maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc = 10000;

        function getUrlParameter(name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
            var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
            var results = regex.exec(location.search);
            return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        };


        function replaceUploadProgressFunc() {
            if (typeof _window.UploadProgressFunc != 'undefined') {
                _window.Base_UploadProgressFunc = _window.UploadProgressFunc;
                _window.UploadProgressFunc = Custom_UploadProgressFunc;
                console.log('replaced dialog');
            } else if (maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc > 0) {
                maxTimeForReplaceUploadProgressFunc -= 100;
                setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);
            }
        }
        setTimeout(replaceUploadProgressFunc, 100);


        function Custom_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state) {
            _window.Base_UploadProgressFunc(percentDone, timeElapsed, state);
            var messageType = ProgressMessage.EMPTY;
            switch (state.status) {
                case 1:
                    messageType = ProgressMessage.VALIDATION;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADING;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    messageType = ProgressMessage.UPLOADED;
                    OpenEditFormForLastItem(state);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    messageType = ProgressMessage.CANCELLED;
                    break;
            }

            function OpenEditFormForLastItem(state) {

                var folderServerRelativeUrl = decodeURIComponent(getUrlParameter('RootFolder'));

                var caml = '';
                caml += "<View>";
                caml += "<Query>";
                caml += "<Where>";

                if (state.files.length > 1) {
                    caml += "<In>";
                    caml += "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>";
                    caml += "<Values>";
                } else {
                    caml += "<Eq>";
                    caml += "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>";
                }

                state.files.forEach(function (file) {
                    //only succesfull uploaded files that arent overwrites
                    console.log(file);
                    if (file.status === 5 /*&& !file.overwrite*/) {
                        caml += "<Value Type='File'>" + file.fileName + "</Value>";
                    }
                }, this);

                if (state.files.length > 1) {
                    caml += "</Values>";
                    caml += "</In>";
                } else {
                    caml += "</Eq>";
                }

                caml += "</Where>";
                caml += "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";
                caml += "</Query>";
                caml += "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields>";
                caml += "<RowLimit>500</RowLimit>";
                caml += "</View>";
                console.log(caml);

                var cntxt = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
                var web = cntxt.get_web();
                var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(window.ctx.ListTitle);
                var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
                query.set_viewXml(caml);

                if(folderServerRelativeUrl !== null && folderServerRelativeUrl !== "") {
                    query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl(folderServerRelativeUrl);
                }

                var items = list.getItems(query);
                cntxt.load(list, 'DefaultEditFormUrl');
                cntxt.load(items);
                cntxt.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                    var listEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();
                    function openEditForItem() {
                        if (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                            var item = listEnumerator.get_current();
                            var id = item.get_id();

                            var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
                            options.title = "Add File Metadata";
                            options.url = list.get_defaultEditFormUrl() + '?ID=' + id;
                            options.autoSize = true;
                            options.dialogReturnValueCallback = openEditForItem;
                            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
                        } else {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                    openEditForItem();
                }, function (error, args) {
                        console.log("failed to get new uploaded items");
                        console.log(error);
                        console.log(args);
                    });
            }
        }
    })(window);
```

Comment: thanks a lot... I will test it next week... 
If I forget to answer the bounty feel please contact me (have a lot on my plate)