# Show DisplayForm after insert new record

Tags: 2013, display-form

I'm looking if there is a way to show an already inserted record instead of returning to the list...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using JavaScript you can change the URL query string `Source` and place the `DisplayForm`

http://spjsblog.com/2011/04/23/redirect-from-newform-to-dispform-or-editform/#comment-195397

Comment: I have already tryied, but when i load my EditForm without id, i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: _spUserId is not defined`

Comment: Ok, i arranged it. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the dialog manually, you can use dialogReturnValueCallback (nicely [described here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38405/sharepoint-modal-help-pass-value-back-to-parent-when-closing))

Or you can add a web part to default form and using jQuery check that the save button was clicked and you can redirect wherever you want (althought you might have issues with obtaining newly created item ID).