# Returning values from DIV based modal popup

Tags: popup

I have created a DIV based modal popup like this:

```
OpenPopUpPageWithDialogOptions({
    title: "Instruciton for Recruiter/Submitter",
    html:**html**,
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult){
        alert(dialogResult); 
    }
});
```

in the **html** I have a DIV with multiple text fields

```
var html = document.createElement('div');
html = 'text inputs (q1, q2, q3)'
```

AND

```
<a href="#" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel); return false;">Close Dialog</a>\
<a href="#" onclick="alert("Hit the ball");SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK); return false;">OK</a>';
```

As soon as dialog's OK button is clicked I need to pass the values of q1, q2, q3 text areas to the parent page. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please refer this solution here..http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38405/sharepoint-modal-help-pass-value-back-to-parent-when-closing

Comment: Is that solution helps you? If not than please let me know so I can give you workaround for the same.

Comment: Thanks for pointing, I had seen that earlier, but my one is htm (div) based not url based. Hence, in this call back function CloseCallback(result, **target**) {}, I don't find any value in the target variable!